# Python function to extrude plane in edit mode

Tags: python, mesh, bmesh

For a project I'm working on, I've taken the lazy way out. I wish to create a box similar to this in Python:

[image: Simple box]

The final version will have more than two edge loops and they won't be uniformly spaced, but this is enough to explain the problem.

I've done this by creating the plane and then using `bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move()` to extrude three times.  In the final version instead of using the same extrusion distance each time, I would use an array to get the right distance.  Here's my Python code to create this object:

```py
import bpy
col = bpy.data.collections['Collection']
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("base mesh")
obj = bpy.data.objects.new("thing", mesh)
col.objects.link(obj)

verts = [(-1, -1, 0), (1, -1, 0), (-1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0)]
edges = [(0, 1), (1, 3), (3, 2), (2, 3)]
faces = [(0, 1, 3, 2)]
mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)
mesh.update()

# Extrude it three times
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
for z in range(0,3):
    bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move(
        TRANSFORM_OT_translate={
            "value":(0, 0, 1),
            "orient_type":'NORMAL',
            "orient_matrix":((0, -1, 0), (1, 0, -0), (0, 0, 1)),
            "orient_matrix_type":'NORMAL',
            "constraint_axis":(False, False, True),
        }
    )

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

Keeping in mind that this is a demo version and the final version will have more layers (edge loops) unevenly spaced, how would you write a function that uses the above data plus an array of offsets to create a similar object?

I've tried incrementing the relative data by 4 each time and expanding the data so that I can do it all in one call to `mesh.from_pydata` but I keep screwing up the code to add the additional side faces to each layer.

Comment: The faces index in the above code is incorrect, so it will result in extra facets.

Comment: @XY I don't understand your comment.  What would a correct value be?

Answer (score 0):

#### Here's another way to extrude a face

for 1000 extrude:
`ops method: 2 second`
`my method: 0.006 second`

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

col = bpy.data.collections['Collection']
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("base mesh")
obj = bpy.data.objects.new("thing", mesh)
col.objects.link(obj)

verts = [(-1, -1, 0), (1, -1, 0), (-1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0)]
edges = [(0, 1), (1, 3), (3, 2), (2, 0)]    # changed
faces = [(0, 1, 3, 2)]
# faces = [(2, 3, 1, 0)]

# given a coplanar polygon, unit vector of normal, list of height
# must 1 face only
def ReturnPrism(verts, face, normal, ListOfHeight):
    vec0, vec1, vec2 = normal

    l = len(verts)
    l1 = l + 1

    # change verts order
    out_faces = [tuple(r for r in range(l))]
    out_edges = [(r, r + 1) for r in range(l)]
    out_edges[-1] = (out_edges[-1][0], 0)
    face_ind_lookup = {e : i for i, e in enumerate(face)}
    out_verts = [verts[face_ind_lookup[r]] for r in range(l)]
    del face_ind_lookup
    # change verts order END

    ind_vert = 0

    for h in ListOfHeight:
        tm_ind_face1 = ind_vert
        tm_ind_face2 = ind_vert + l
        for _ in range(l):
            v = out_verts[ind_vert]
            out_verts.append((
                v[0] + vec0 * h,
                v[1] + vec1 * h,
                v[2] + vec2 * h))

            out_edges.append((ind_vert, ind_vert + l))

            out_faces.append((
                ind_vert,
                ind_vert + 1,
                ind_vert + l1,
                ind_vert + l))

            ind_vert += 1

        F = out_faces[-1]
        new_face = (F[0], tm_ind_face1, tm_ind_face2, F[3])
        out_faces[-1] = new_face

        i = ind_vert
        for _ in range(l):
            out_edges.append((ind_vert, ind_vert + 1))
            ind_vert += 1
        out_edges[-1] = (out_edges[-1][0], i)
        ind_vert = i

    i = len(out_verts)
    out_faces.append(tuple(r for r in range(i - l, i)))

    return out_verts, out_edges, out_faces

new_mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('new_mesh')
new_mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)
normal = new_mesh.polygons[0].normal

# height of edge loops: 1, 2, 3
mesh.from_pydata(*ReturnPrism(verts, faces[0], normal, [r for r in range(1, 4)]))
mesh.update()
bpy.data.meshes.remove(new_mesh)
```

Comment: This doesn't create a square base with a range of 'edge loops'.

Comment: I changed the vertex order in the function so it now works on any ordered face.

Comment: Now works with my data with one exception:  Whichever face normal the original quad has you generate the opposite direction normal for the added faces.  If I correctly set `faces = [(0, 3, 1, 2)]` so that the original face's normal points out; the created faces' normals face in. If I set it to my original  `[0, 1, 3, 2]` order then the original face's normal faces in but the generate faces have normals facing out.

Comment: Get the normalized normal from `polygons[0].normal`, then it has different directions on different face index orders.

Comment: This version only generates the first face